# How to test a specific module in React Testing Library (RTL)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In RTL after navigating to the specific component directory then trying to test components under the module called `Module.spec.js` by using the command `env DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=50000 npm test -- Module --watch` but it tests all components with the same module name but I want only one module to be tested. Here I'm using Jest as the test runner.

Could anyone please suggest to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Jest as the test runner which I'm going to assume you are as that's standard for react testing library. When running the tests in watch mode `jest --watch` you can press `p` to filter which test file(s) to run. Type in the path of the file to get an exact match for only that file.

For example `modules/Module1`

Comment: I appreciate your answer but my component file names are the same then It's difficult to identify a specific file name to filter out

Comment: You can include folder names in the filter. Something like src/modules/Module1 would then run all spec files in the Module1 folder

Comment: Yes, it is working if I just use like this `modules/Module1`. I think you can mention this in your answer so that people can take advantage of it. @spirift